# "Invalid Column Name" thrown In Java Spring Batch, but not in Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: java, spring, oracle

Using Java Spring Batch, I am generating a file based off of a query sent to a Oracle database:

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(CLIENT.FirstName, chr(13), ' ')
FROM client_table CLIENT;
```

This query works fine when I run it in Oracle SQL Developer when I spool the result, but doesn't work when I try to utilize it to generate a file in Java Spring batch. It throws the error:

```
Message=Encountered an error executing step preparePrimaryIpData in job extract-primary-ip-job
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Attempt to process next row failed; bad SQL grammar [

             SELECT 
             REPLACE(CLIENT.FirstName, chr(13), ' ')
             FROM client_table CLIENT

 ]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:237)
```

Why is this working fine in Oracle Sql Developer but not when I try to utilize it in Java Spring Batch?

Also, the alias is necessary, because my actual query has a lot more joins, I just wanted to simplify it as an example.

Comment: I'm inclined to speculate that the Spring JDBC driver is attempting to parse your query, and chokes when it does not recognize the Oracle `REPLACE()` function and / or `chr()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some thing like :

SELECT REPLACE(CLIENT.FirstName, chr(13), ' ')  columnNameX FROM client_table CLIENT

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck.

Answer (score 2):

you need to check the spelling of columns in your query as well as where you will be getting the result set. I was facing the same problem and the problem was in spelling in one of the "rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME")".

Answer (score 1):

It is not the sql that has failed but you are misspelling the column name somewhere in your code.